# How can Emacs set an environment/shell variable in a subordinate shell?

Tags: shell, comint, subprocess, environment

I often use subordinate shells within Emacs.  (I instantiate these shells with `M-x shell`.)

I put all these shells under `auto-save-mode` (through my `shell-mode-hook`; see below).

Is there some way that I can have Emacs set an environment variable *in a subordinate shell* equal to the value of `buffer-auto-save-file-name`?

---

For what it's worth, below is the hook code I use to put my subordinate shells under `auto-save-mode`:

```
;; NB: I define the global variable auto-saves-dir elsewhere in my init file.

(defun cd-to-auto-saves-dir ()
  (unless (file-directory-p auto-saves-dir)
    (make-directory auto-saves-dir t))
  (cd auto-saves-dir))

(add-hook
    'shell-mode-hook
    (lambda ()    
        ;; the silliness with cd-ing to/fro auto-saves-dir is the
        ;; only way I've found to trick Emacs into putting the
        ;; auto-save'd file in auto-saves-dir
        (let ((orig-dir default-directory))
           (cd-to-auto-saves-dir)
           (auto-save-mode)
           (cd orig-dir))
        )
    )
```

Comment: I hack `comint-exec-1` to create a custom buffer-local `process-environment` containing the environmental variables that I like.  You might want to consider doing something similar.

Comment: By the way, `(let ((default-directory auto-saves-dir)) (auto-save-mode))` should work fine, assuming `auto-saves-dir` exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After (re)reading the code of the `shell` function, here's what I'd do:

```
(advice-add 'make-comint-in-buffer :around
            #'my-enable-auto-save-in-shell)

(defun my-enable-auto-save-in-shell (origfun procname &rest args)
  (if (not (equal procname "shell"))
      (apply origfun procname args)   ;; Not a shell, nothing to do.
    ;; Enable auto-save-mode.
    (let ((default-directory auto-saves-dir)) (auto-save-mode))
    ;; Pass the auto-save file name to the subprocess.
    (let ((process-environment
           `(,(concat "EMACS_AUTO_SAVE_FILE_NAME="
                      buffer-auto-save-file-name)
             . ,process-environment)))
      (apply origfun procname args))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to the end of your lambda() routine:

```
(goto-char (point-max))
(insert (concat "export EMACS_AS_FILE=" buffer-auto-save-file-name))
```

The shell command to assign your variable will automatically appear on the command line; simply hit enter to set it.

Answer (score 1):

```el
(let ((process-environment
       `(,(concat "BUFFER_AUTO_SAVE_FILE_NAME="
                   buffer-auto-save-file-name)
         ,@process-environment)))
  (shell))
```

Comment: I don't think this will cut it because this uses the `buffer-auto-save-file-name` of the buffer from which we run `shell` not the value inside that buffer.

Comment: Yeah, right.   34

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `with-environment-variables` macro.

```lisp
(let ((buffer-auto-save-file-name "test-file.txt"))
  (with-environment-variables (("BUFFER_AUTO_SAVE_FILE_NAME" buffer-auto-save-file-name))
    (shell)))
```